# Does Java7's SDP support help with 10 gig networking?

Tags: java, performance, java-7, low-latency

Does the new Java7 SDP offer any advantages for 10 gig networking?

We use SolarFlare 10 gig NICs, which offer DMA via the OpenOnload driver.  I'm not familiar with Infiniband, but I'm curious if there is a way to use SDP to reduce latency.

Answer (score 1):

I have performed some tests with SDP over loopback and it didn't help performance.  AFAIK, Unless SDP supports your network adapter specificly I would assume it is not better.  You could test it to see if it improves performance.

However you really should ask Solarflare as it might not even work. Their support is usually very good.

Comment: SDP is deprecated and OFED no more come with SDP support. Hence Java's SDP also fails. Any solutions?

Comment: @RoboAlex what is the problem you are trying to solve?  BTW You might find this interesting http://torusware.com/product/java-fast-sockets-jfs/

Comment: I have collection of Infiniband enabled machines. I would like to add RDMA feature to my application which is in Java. Please answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465538/infiniband-in-java