# Infiniband in Java

Tags: java, sockets, hpc, infiniband, rdma

As you all know, OFED's Socket Direct protocol is [deprecated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sockets_Direct_Protocol) and OFED's 3.x releases do not come with SDP at all. Hence, Java's [SDP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sdp/sockets/) also fails to work. I was wondering what is the proper method to program infiniband in Java? Is there any portable solution other than just writing JNI code?

My requirement is achieve [RDMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_direct_memory_access) among collection of infiniband powered machines.

Comment: I would ask Infiniband what their support for Java is.  In many cases, vendor provide a drop-in replacement for system libraries allowing you to use their user space drivers without writing code.

Answer (score 2):

[jVerbs](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2523631) might be what you're looking for.  [Here's](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.api.70.doc/com.ibm.net.rdma/com/ibm/net/rdma/jverbs/verbs/package-summary.html) a little bit of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

jVerbs looks interesting otherwise you might like to try rsockets with LD_PRELOAD.

Answer (score 1):

Use Fast-MPJ or any other mpi in java which gives infinband device layer support. open-mpi was expected to release openMPI for java recently.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for SDP replacement try IBM's JSOR API - it uses the same idea of providing RDMA behind good old Java sockets. It is faster than SDP and still supported. Works fine with OFED 3.1.